# XFS Log I/O Error Detected.....but WHY?

Tags: hard-drive, xfs

I added a brand new drive to my Ubuntu 20.04 system, got it all set up, formatted it XFS, and now twice in two days I have had the system crash with the following error on the console:

```
XFS (sdb1): Log I/O Error Detected. Shutting down filesystem
XFS (sdb1): Please unmount the filesystem and rectify the problem(s)
```

Unfortunately, there is nothing in the logs that lead me to any conclusion as to what the problem might be. This is what is in dmesg:

```
[  295.495988] XFS (sdb1): Metadata CRC error detected at xfs_inobt_read_verify+0x1a/0xc0 [xfs], xfs_inobt block 0x30 
[  295.498465] XFS (sdb1): Unmount and run xfs_repair
[  295.515359] XFS (sdb1): metadata I/O error in "xfs_trans_read_buf_map" at daddr 0x30 len 8 error 74
[  295.517401] XFS (sdb1): xfs_do_force_shutdown(0x1) called from line 325 of file fs/xfs/xfs_trans_buf.c. Return address = 0000000099c0d7d2
```

Of course, trying to search for the error led me pretty much nowhere, and the problem has cropped up several times. Fortunately, this is **not** a production system **yet**! I did check all the cables, pulled and reseated the drive, rebooted the system, and even did about 10TB of dd to and from it. Then it happened again. I don't know if I am looking at a bad cable, bad hard drive (smart shows no issues with the drive), bad SAS controller, or what

I simply cannot find any good troubleshooting for this error so I am hoping someone here has seen the same thing and may be able to help me out.

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the drive health?  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools

Comment: Yes, as mentioned above I have run smart checks against the drive with no errors at all.

Comment: It could be a bad cable, it could be a bad power supply.  It could be a bad motherboard, RAM, controller on the board, etc.  There are so many things that it could be causing the issue.  The only thing I have ever been able to come up with on a system that I use as a NAS with a RAID 5 array in it is that vibrations from fans over time have caused my SATA cables to come loose and make the drive(s) appear as if they are failing.  I purchased locking SATA cables for all my drives and have not had issues with it since.

Comment: OK, brand new cables, another brand new, never used hard drive, this one a 12TB, same exact problem:

```[229182.496256] XFS (sdd1): log I/O error -5
[229182.497862] XFS (sdd1): xfs_do_force_shutdown(0x2) called from line 1250 of file fs/xfs/xfs_log.c. Return address = 00000000e29fea86
[229182.497864] XFS (sdd1): Log I/O Error Detected. Shutting down filesystem
[229182.499398] XFS (sdd1): Please unmount the filesystem and rectify the problem(s)```

I find it absolutely amazing that there is zero references on what might be causing the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Optionally, skip to the end for the surprise solution. This usually occurs when the disk is close to 90% full. There is no solution as of yet, besides transfer the data to a different drive, and don't fill up the xfs system past 85%.

This problem can occur when the xfs log carries uncommitted data, which should be resolved by umounting and mounting again. But when it doesn't, you need to run `sync` from a command line after a successful mount.

Sync attempts to commit the cache buffers, some of which must be done within the xfs log (xfs, ext4, and others are logging file systems that cache metadata to a log either within the same volume as the file system, or a separate log file in a different file system.)

But `sync` can cause the same problem with the xfs file system shutting down and the block device (i.e. /dev/sdc) vanishing to prevent damage to the file system.

One quick and dirty technique is to use `xfs_repair -L device` with the file system unmounted. That will zero the log. It should be safe after the device node is recreated, the file system is mounted (might take a while), umounted, and then zero the logs.

If your using a SSD, you're going to have to trim the drive after you zero the log, or behavior can repeat itself. Presently, I'm attempting to move the xfs log to a separate file, and make it about 200GB for a 1TB NVMe USB drive, reconcile the cache buffers, trim the xfs drive, and put the log back in the 1TB xfs volume.

But the data is a local Debian amd64 mirror, so it can be rebuilt. If it was irreplaceable data, I'd mount it, use rsync to move as much data as possible before a file system shutdown, and then `sync` without the xfs volume mounted, to make sure all the data is written, and get the xfs volume mounted again, and delete everything I was able to transfer to other storage.

If you can give the xfs system 15-20% of the drive, then you should be able to commit the cache buffers and run `sync` to zero everything. But I would still run `xfs_repair -L device` to zero the logs.

To solve this problem, I formatted the USB drive, and rebuilt the Debian mirror. I have another identical enclosure, and lo and behold, it started with the same erratic behavior as the one with the Debian mirror on it.

Couldn't be coincidence. NO, it was not. Two identical USB enclosures, 2 1TB NVMe drives, and the only common thread was the USB cable. I switched cables, and the problem was cured!

So much for *that* 6 hours of my life! But I did learn how to make a separate log partition, which seems like a better way to go. So it wasn't a total waste.

The remainder of the post is sound material minus 200GB journal size, which for a 1TB drive might require 20-30MB. I made the journal partition end 20MB before the last sector on the drive, because I believe xfs will apportion that free space if sectors go bad in the external journal.